# Assign domain to IP address

Tags: java, http, sockets

How do i go about making my Java app run an HTTP server on some socket (e.g 172.16.1.10:8080) and make it so that when another computer on the network connects to a domain (e.g `http://myjavadomain.com`) it gets redirected to the socket?

Comment: Which web container you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a fully fledged HTTP server then you will probably want to use some external library. For instance, [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is written in Java, but there is also SUN's [httpserver package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html). If it's just a simple socket server you're after, you can use the built-in classes from the java.net package:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);

while (running) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    handleConnection(socket);
}
```

This will listen for incoming socket connections on port 8080 and create a new `Socket` whenever a client connects. You can then communicate with the client through the `Socket`'s `InputStream` and `OuputStream`, which you would probably do in a separate Thread, so that your `ServerSocket` can continue listening for incoming connections from other clients.

As for the second part of your question: by default, a web browser will connect to port 80, and there are several ways you could do port forwarding. One possible solution using iptables is given on [this website](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 172.16.1.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

But the easiest solution would be to just specify the port number directly when connecting to your machine, e.g.

```
http://myjavadomain.com:8080
```

This is assuming that your DNS is configured so that it resolves myjavadomain.com to 172.16.1.10 already.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache Tomcat then the below configuration will helpful to you.

Fot Apache Tomcat you have to make on Host entry in the configuration location of the TOMCAT_HOME location.

Follow below steps that will be helpful to you

1)  Find the `server.xml` file in the `conf` location of `TOMCAT_HOME`
2)  in the `server.xml` file make the below host entry

```
<Host name="www.xyz.com" debug="0" appBase="webapps/mynewhost" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" directory="logs"  prefix="mynewhost_log." suffix=".txt" timestamp="true"/>
</Host>


In appBase property place the location of your web app
```

3)  Now in browser open the above url.